# jQuery function to only run on the element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement an accordian style box on some content. However there are 4-6 of these boxes on 1 template, all with different classes for obvious reasons. However I want to try and make the code as easy to read as possible and I don't want to duplicate the code for each class name. I'm assumung jQuerys (this) method would work but i'm not 100% sure how to use it.

Here is my JS code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".block-50_hoverHeader").click(function (){
           //alert("clicked");
            $(".scrollText").slideToggle(1000);

        });

        });


</script>
```

So the .scrollText class is the div that holds all the content which needs to be displayed after the onClick function. But currently when I click the header all the .scollText divs appear on the page. So i want it to only appear on the parent header div that is being clicked.

Here the HTML:

```
<div class="block-50 left textHoverWrapOne">
    <img src="" alt="" /> (Image working as BG Image)
    <div class="block-50_hoverHeader"><p>This is a header!</p></div>
    <div class="block-50_textHoverOne trans_click scrollText">
        This is the content that needs to be displayed after the 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `scrollText` relative to the clicked `block-50_hoverHeader` element. In this case it is the next sibling, so you can use .next()

Inside the event handler `this` points to the element in which the handler is registered, in this case it is the `block-50_hoverHeader` element, so we can find the next `scrollText` using `$(this).next()`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".block-50_hoverHeader").click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/46BjQ/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  I prefer to grab the shared parent and then use `find` as I find this is a bit less likely to break due to minor modifications to the html structure.

```
$(".block-50_hoverHeader").click(function (){

    $(this).closest(".textHoverWrapOne").find(".scrollText").slideToggle(1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not targeting the whole div??

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".block-50").click(function () {
        $(this).find('.scrollText').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```